# R calculating Earth Mover's Distance for large rasters

Tags: r, matrix, raster, similarity

I am trying to get a quantitative estimate of the (dis)similarity between two rasters with the emd2d (from emdist library, ver. 0.3-1).
The following code runs fine for small matrices (~35x35), but my rasters are much larger (~5000x3000) and I am getting a memory error:

*Error in emdr(A, B, dist = dist, ...) :*
*Unable to memory (-1608.8 MB) in emdist*

Here is a sample code to illustrate the problem:

```
#test case:
library(emdist)
Rows = 40
Cols = 40
Mat1 = matrix( 
       seq(1,Rows*Cols), 
       nrow = Rows, 
       ncol = Cols) 

m0 <- matrix(0, Rows, Cols)
Mat_Rand = apply(m0, c(1,2), function(x) rnorm(1)) #sample(c(0,1),1))
Mat2 = Mat1 * Mat_Rand

emd2d(Mat1,Mat2,dist="euclidean")
```

I am running R R version 3.2.5 on a win7 64bit.

Thanks

Ilik

Comment: Please specify the problem? You likely ran out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass the limit of memory, you can take sample of matrix, e.g. randomly select 30 out of 40 per row and 30 out of 40 per col to form a new matrix, which reduce the pairs from more than 1 million to less than half million.

```
seed.set(1234)
row.rand = sample(1:40, 30)
col.rand = sample(1:40, 30)
Mat1.new = matrix(NA, 30,30)
Mat2.new = matrix(NA, 30,30)
for(i in 1:length(row.rand)){
    for(j in 1:length(col.rand)){
        Mat1.new[i,j] = Mat1[row.rand[i],col.rand[j]]
        Mat2.new[i,j] = Mat2[row.rand[i],col.rand[j]]
    }
} 
emd2d(Mat1.new, Mat2.new)
```